# Result of expression 'xxxx' is not a constructor in JS

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

Trying to create an object in Javascript (for Appcelerator/Titanium).
The "object" is defined like this:

```
function server () {
    this.cacheimages = 0;
    this.login = "";
    this.name = "";
    this.root = "";
    this.signup = "";
    this.useimages = 0;
    this.userexists = "";
    this.isdefault = 0;

    return this;
}
```

In the same file, in another function when I run this line: `var server = new server();` I get the error `Result of expression 'server' is not a constructor.`
I have tried it with and without the "return" line, neither work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you later on again do `var server = new server();`? If so, that's your problem, since you replaced `server` with `server`. Try renaming your variable or function (e.g. `function Server`) so that they don't collide. _Many, including myself, use the convention that constructor functions are named with a leading capital letter._

Comment: Take out the return and try using another variable name. i.e. var myserver = new server();

Comment: +1 to Phrogz's suggestion: *use the convention that constructor functions are named with a leading capital letter.* Even better: avoid them altogether! They just break when the caller forgets `new`. Write ordinary functions instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you change the name of the variable?

```
var server2 = new server();
```

Comment: +1 The point is that `function server()` creates a variable `server`, which is then being overwritten.

Comment: Yes, and by the way, `return this` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are '[first class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)' in javascript, meaning they are variables (or better still: objects, like everything in javascript is an object). So your constructor function could also be written as

```
var server = function() {
 //[...]
}
```

Now, if you declare a new variable called `server`, this overwrites the constructor function, being a variable too.

It's common practice to upcase the name of constructor functions. If you use `function Server() { ... }`, `var server = new Server` (no need for parenthesis by the way) you're fine.